# google maps android api v2 error "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key."

Tags: android, google-maps

I have problem with connecting with google map API V2 and android..in my app i have use this link 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=48.85827758964043,2.294543981552124&radius=5000&types=airport&sensor=true&key="API_KEY".
I have create project in my google account and get API_KEY but this API_KEY not work this give me error like : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key.",

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=yourlatitude,yourlongitude&radius=5000&sensor=true&key=SERVERKEY use server key not android key

Comment: @Ram server key also give me same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be creating a browser key instead of an android key. I faced similar problem when I accidentely created an android key for Google Cloud Messaging instead of a server key. Please check which key is required for your purpose. For google maps v2 you need android key and for google places api you need a server key(searched google but not so sure on this one never used it). So basically you need two keys.
Update: You need server key for places api.

by @Illegal Argument